# How the website owner keep track of your times of access?

Tags: computability, network-flow

To be specific, I am using the online website of Strait Times News. It limits users to 30 articles to read per month. I just do not understand how do they know you are accessing? We use different IP each time we go online, don't we?
 Is there anyway to hack this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this website keeps track but I can tell you the general flow how usual websites keep track of user's data.

If the you are registered user on the site it doesn't matter which ip you use it can be tracked easily.
To be more specific when you read the complete article a tracker can be anywhere from page-end scroll to read-more button.

Edit1: Looks Like the website you are talking tracks user based on (article click+ip+ cookie) so it is easy just to choose new ip + incognito browsing to get 30 article limit each time.

Comment: Welcome! This particular question is [off-topic](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but, also, your answer is rather speculative and lacking detail. Stack Exchange sites are looking for reasonably detailed answers, based on knowledge rather than guesswork.

Comment: Thanks!! I could have provided more detailed specification of tracking but thought the question only requires some way to outperform the functionality rather than understanding it hence the the idea of ip+incognito anyways will provide detailed solution next time.